# Split a python list into other "sublists" i.e smaller lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a python list which runs into 1000's. Something like:

```
data=["I","am","a","python","programmer".....]
```

where, len(data)= say 1003

I would now like to create a subset of this list (data) by splitting the orginal list into chunks of 100. So, at the end, Id like to have something like:

```
data_chunk1=[.....] #first 100 items of list data
data_chunk2=[.....] #second 100 items of list data
.
.
.
data_chunk11=[.....] # remainder of the entries,& its len <=100, len(data_chunk_11)=3
```

Is there a pythonic way to achieve this task? Obviously I can use data[0:100] and so on, but I am assuming that is terribly non-pythonic and very inefficient.

Many thanks.

Comment: You could use [numpy's array_split function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html#numpy.array_split) e.g., `np.array_split(np.array(data), 20)` to split into 20 nearly equal size chunks. To make sure chunks are exactly equal in size use `np.split`.

Answer (score 505, accepted):

I'd say

```
chunks = [data[x:x+100] for x in range(0, len(data), 100)]
```

If you are using python 2.x instead of 3.x, you can be more memory-efficient by using `xrange()`, changing the above code to:

```
chunks = [data[x:x+100] for x in xrange(0, len(data), 100)]
```

Comment: I'd go with that too. You might be able to do it in a more 'pythonic way' with itertools, but it will be ugly as sin!

Comment: If you have a list and want a list, there's no reason to bother with itertools. They only make sense if you want to split up a stream of data without ever creating the entire thing.

Comment: Using itertools would actually be the less pythonic way to do it, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 47):

Actually I think using plain slices is the best solution in this case:

```
for i in range(0, len(data), 100):
    chunk = data[i:i + 100]
    ...
```

If you want to avoid copying the slices, you could use `itertools.islice()`, but it doesn't seem to be necessary here.

The `itertools()` documentation also contains the famous "grouper" pattern:

```
def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    "grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```

You would need to modify it to treat the last chunk correctly, so I think the straight-forward solution using plain slices is preferable.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I did think of your first plain slice solution, but then thought its maybe too inefficient and too naive of me.. I am a bit surprised that there isnt a pythonic way (one liners) to achieve this task :(

Answer (score 20):

```
chunks = [data[100*i:100*(i+1)] for i in range(len(data)/100 + 1)]
```

This is equivalent to the accepted answer. For example, shortening to batches of 10 for readability:

```
data = range(35)
print [data[x:x+10] for x in xrange(0, len(data), 10)]
print [data[10*i:10*(i+1)] for i in range(len(data)/10 + 1)]
```

Outputs:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19], [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29], [30, 31, 32, 33, 34]]
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19], [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29], [30, 31, 32, 33, 34]]
```

Comment: That's not what's being asked.

Comment: Actually it is equivalent, except for a bug where the last batch is missing, now fixed.

Comment: What if your data isn't divisible by 10 though?

Comment: @AARon It won't matter. The last list will be smaller

Comment: I wish that your data was `data = range(35, 70)` to separate it from the indexes. And I kinda wish you had put the increment of 10 into a variable to make it clear that it is a value that has to be the same multiple places. But I still really like your answer.