# Put quotes around a variable string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I have a JavaScript variable:

```
var text = "http://example.com"
```

Text can be multiple links. How can I put '' around the variable string?

I want the strings to, for example, look like this:

```
"'http://example.com'"
```

Comment: What you want isn't particularly clear. Could you give an example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: can you elaborate on multiple links??

Comment: By multiple link you mean there will be some separator between the urls? like "http://example.com ; http://google.com" Can you please provide an example?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

```
var text = "\"http://example.com\"";
```

Whatever your text, to wrap it with `"`, you need to put them and escape inner ones with `\`. Above will result in:

```
"http://example.com"
```

Comment: Down votes other as well in that case. Also let me know what YOU need to have explained ?

Comment: Dan's highest voted answer has no description either, hmm.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9671301/559850

Comment: can you share the source where you learned it?

Answer (score 34):

```
var text = "http://example.com";

text = "'"+text+"'";
```

Would attach the single quotes (') to the front and the back of the string.

Answer (score 18):

You can add these single quotes with template literals:

```js
var text = "http://example.com"
var quoteText = `'${text}'`

console.log(quoteText)
```

Docs are [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Browsers that support template literals listed [here](https://caniuse.com/template-literals).

Answer (score 16):

I think, the best and easy way for you, to put value inside quotes is:

```
JSON.stringify(variable or value)
```

Comment: Note that this will also backslash-escape things like newlines and tabs, which may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score 9):

Try:

`var text = "'" +  "http://example.com" + "'";`

Answer (score 7):

To represent the text below in JavaScript:

```
"'http://example.com'"
```

Use:

```
"\"'http://example.com'\""
```

Or:

```
'"\'http://example.com\'"'
```

Note that: We always need to escape the quote that we are surrounding the string with using \

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/efcwG/

**General Pointers:**

- You can use quotes inside a string, as long as they don't match the
     quotes surrounding the string:

Example

```
var answer="It's alright";
var answer="He is called 'Johnny'";
var answer='He is called "Johnny"';
```

- Or you can put quotes inside a string by using the \ escape
  character:

Example

```
var answer='It\'s alright';
var answer="He is called \"Johnny\"";
```

- Or you can use a combination of both as shown on top.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_string.asp

Answer (score 3):

let's think urls = "http://example1.com http://example2.com"

```
function somefunction(urls){
var urlarray = urls.split(" ");
var text = "\"'" + urlarray[0] + "'\"";
}
```

output will be text = "'http://example1.com'"

Answer (score 3):

In case of array like

```
result = [ '2015',  '2014',  '2013',  '2011' ],
```

it gets tricky if you are using escape sequence like:

```
result = [ \'2015\',  \'2014\',  \'2013\',  \'2011\' ].
```

Instead, good way to do it is to wrap the array with single quotes as follows:

`result = "'"+result+"'";`

Answer (score 2):

You can escape " with \

```
var text="\"word\"";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/beKpE/

Answer (score 1):

```
var text = "\"http://www.example1.com\"; \"http://www.example2.com\"";
```

Using escape sequence of " (quote), you can achieve this

You can place singe quote (') inside double quotes without any issues
Like this

```
var text = "'http://www.ex.com';'http://www.ex2.com'"
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume you have a bunch of urls separated by spaces. In this case, you could do this:

```
function quote(text) {
  var urls = text.split(/ /)
  for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) urls[i] = "'" + urls[i] + "'"
  return urls.join(" ")
}
```

This function takes a string like `"http://example.com http://blarg.test"` and returns a string like `"'http://example.com' 'http://blarg.test'"`.

It works very simply: it takes your string of urls, splits it by spaces, surrounds each resulting url with quotes and finally combines all of them back with spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Another easy way to wrap a string is to extend the Javascript String prototype:

```
String.prototype.quote = function() { return "\"" + this + "\""; };
```

Use it like this:

```
var s = "abc";
console.log( "unwrapped: " + s + ", wrapped: " + s.quote() );
```

and you will see:

```
unwrapped: abc, wrapped: "abc"
```

Answer (score -2):

This can be one of several solutions:

```
var text = "http://example.com";

JSON.stringify(text).replace('\"', '\"\'').replace(/.$/, '\'"')
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.