# Add double quotes to string which is stored in variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have variable which i am getting from DB string url, But the url does not have quotes to url i need to add the quotes to it below is my code.

```
 var audioUrl
 url is having string like http://xxxxx/xxx/xx-xx-123.m4a without double quotes
 audioUrl= (data.url)

 i need convert data.url value to "http://xxxxx/xxx/xx-xx-123.m4a"

       Circle Jplayer
       var audio="http://xxxxx/xxx/xx-xx-123.m4a"
       var myOtherOne = new CirclePlayer("#jquery_jplayer_2",
        {
            m4a: audio,
        }
```

Comment: What do you have when calling `console.log(audioUrl)` ?

Comment: http://xxxxx/xxx/xx-xx-123.m4a i have url without quotes

Comment: If I've understood correctly, just concatenate it: `audioUrl = '"' + data.url + '"'`

Comment: `audioUrl = '"' + data.url + '"'` - beaten to the punch

Comment: just curious as to why you would require quotes in it?

Comment: This is normal no to see the quotes. Why do you need quotes ? What is your error ?

Comment: my player will play song only with quotes so, i need to add it

Comment: @kittysarvaj I think that your problem is somewhere else. You receive a string from your database. This has double quotes because it is a string but you won't see it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Put quotes around a variable string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714759/put-quotes-around-a-variable-string-in-javascript)

Comment: Kitty Sarvag, As @Weedoze says, there's something wrong with your player. You have already received the data in string format.

Comment: How are you inserting the string into your HTML? This sounds like an http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: i am using circle  Jplayer player in which, i am passing the valiable into it,it works in android, in ios its not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var audioUrl = "\""+ data.url+  "\"";
```

Whatever your get audioUrl and you want to wrap it with ", you need to put them and escape inner ones with . Above will result in:

```
 "http://xxxxx/xxx/xx-xx-123.m4a"
```

OR if you are using the single quotes then no need to use the escape character.

```
var audioUrl = '"'+ data.url+  '"';
```

Comment: Can you please upvote the answer so that when other see it they will find that the answer has been fully accepted by you.

Answer (score 9):

If possible, I'd use ES6 syntax for this:

```
`"${data.url}"`
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest way

```
var audioUrl = '"' + (data.url) + '"'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem that comes up all the time for me and it does get frustrating.
A simple solution is to create global variables and use them in your strings as needed like so:

```
var singleQuote = " ' ";

var doubleQuote = ' " ';
```

Hope this helps others.