# TimeStamp error + postgresql + node.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, datetime

I have a value for time as `2017-05-25T18:44:56` . The following is my table structure

```
CREATE TABLE aaaaaa (
    enroll_id bigserial primary key,
    time timestamp with time zone NOT NULL        
);
```

When i insert the above value into time column its throws the following error  `{ error: syntax error at or near "T18"}`

How can i solve this? Please share your ideas. Thanks in advance.

My insert Query:

```
var query = 'Insert Into aaaaa (enroll_id, time,) values ('+item.EnrollNumber+', '+item.time+')';
```

Comment: Its saying syntax error in your query. Share your insert query here.

Comment: Also, what package do you use?

Comment: I've successfully inserted the value into the table, so it is not postgresql fault. You can always cast value to timestamp.

Comment: You should never concatenate queries manually, you're supposed to use the driver to escape all the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to surround time value with quotes.

```
Insert Into aaaa (enroll_id, time) values (19, '2017-05-25T18:44:56')
```

and query construction in javascript should look similiar to

```
var a=15;
var b='2017-05-25T18:44:56';
var query = "Insert Into aaaaa (enroll_id, time,) values ("+a+", '"+b+"')";
```

Check here
[Put quotes around a variable string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714759/put-quotes-around-a-variable-string-in-javascript)

Comment: im constructin query like this   `var query = 'Insert Into aaaaa (enroll_id, time,) values ('+item.EnrollNumber+', '+item.time+')';` How can i modify this to form the above query