# Add quotation marks to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm struggling with something in JQuery and I don't get it. I'm trying to add quotation marks to a variable in a parameter for a function.

```
$(".menu").append("<div class='language' onclick='changeLanguage("+ input.translation +");'>Change language</div>");
```

The onclick-output has to be something like `changeLanguage('en')` and not `changeLanguage(en)`, where "en" is a string and not a variabele. But everything I'm trying ends in an error.

What I am doing wrong? In which way to I have to add the quotation marks to get it work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Put quotes around a variable string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714759/put-quotes-around-a-variable-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
$(".menu").append("<div class='language' onclick='changeLanguage(\""+ input.translation +"\");'>Change language</div>");
```