# How to show number as a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

So, I was making the footer for my website just now and I wanted to make the year shown on the footer always be the current year. I need to use JavaScript, so I wrote some code for it:

```js
function loadCopyrightText() {
  var today = new Date();
  var year = today.getFullYear();
}
```

But now I have a problem. I want to show the variable `year` as a string like this:

```
“2019”
```

I researched the `Number.toString()` method and it did not solve the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Put quotes around a variable string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714759/put-quotes-around-a-variable-string-in-javascript)

Comment: How did it not solve your question?  Could you go into more detail about what you attempted

Answer (score 2):

I like template literals, especially this is a good case for that.

As the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) states:

> Template literals are string literals allowing embedded expressions. You can use multi-line strings and string interpolation features with them. They were called "template strings" in prior editions of the ES2015 specification.

You can do something like this:

```js
const getCurrentYear = () => new Date().getFullYear();
const copyrightText = `© ${getCurrentYear()} All Rights Reserved`;
console.log(copyrightText);
```

Or if you want to keep the double quotes as in your question, you can do the following:

```js
const getCurrentYear = () => new Date().getFullYear();
const copyrightText = `© “${getCurrentYear()}” All Rights Reserved`;
console.log(copyrightText);
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use template literals

```js
const today = new Date();
const year = today.getFullYear();
const yearWithQuotes = `"${year}"`
console.log(yearWithQuotes)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) [as a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#String_conversion) (not as a constructor i.e. without the `new` keyword) to coerce your element to a string.

```js
const today = new Date();
const year = today.getFullYear();
 
const stringified = '“'+String(year)+'”'
console.log(stringified)
console.log(typeof stringified)
```

Comment: But then we can just do `"“"+year+"”"`  ^^

Answer (score 0):

you can cast by doing `year = year + ""`

Answer (score 0):

```
function loadCopyrightText() {
  var today = new Date();
  return today.getFullYear().toString();
}
```