# Parsing JSON object with java object as value

Tags: json, parsing

I am trying to convert a JSON object to JavaScript object. JSON object i received from webservice 
contain java object

```
{
 gateway:com.admin.mypackage.addreesoftheobject;
}
```

JSON.parse in JavaScript, failed to parse this field, throwing exception, invalid character 'c'

is there any other way of parsing my JavaScript object.

Thanks and Regards
Biswarup

Answer (score 0):

The problem is it's incorrect JSON. You can use validators for checking:

[jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/)

[jsonformatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

if you change your JSON to :

```
{
   "gateway":"com.admin.mypackage.addreesoftheobject;"
}
```

it should be parsed correctly.

Comment: My webservice returns this json, so can not change it accordingly, is there any way to make it a valid json, thanks in advance

Comment: ok, how about correct input text? like here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/9714804