# concatenate string to variable within double quotes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, string

I wanted to concatenate the value of variable `i` to string `item`. i tried like below but it's not working.  How can i achieve this?

```
var tableString = "<td><input type='text' id='item'+i><td>"
```

i've already gone through this link: [Put quotes around a variable string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714759/put-quotes-around-a-variable-string-in-javascript) .
Can i get some help on this?

Comment: you want to make id like this? `item1`, `item2`, `itme3`....

Comment: @Dali yes exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use variables inside string, you have to use template literal like this.

```
var tableString = `<td><input type='text' id='item${i}'><td>`
```