# extract div tag entries that are part of a table using python scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

Im trying to extract some data on a webpage using python scrapy. I don't know enough HTML/CSS to know if this is well formatted, but it doesn't appear to be. The target information I am interested in has a pattern as shown below. A Table contains a set of entries (Name, Year, Int1, Int2) that I am interested in extracting. But these are not in the standard TD tags, instead they are part of DIV tags. here's an example:

```
<table width='100%'>
<tr>
<td width='50%'>
<div style='width: 10px; float: left'>&nbsp;</div>
     <div style='width: 232px; float: left'>Mr. Richard D. Hanson</div>
     <div style='width: 40px; float: left'>1989</div>
     <div style='width: 88px; float: left; text-align: right'>1</div>
     <div style='width: 88px; float: left; text-align: right'>27</div></td><td width='50%'><div style='width: 10px; float: left'>&nbsp;</div>
     <div style='width: 232px; float: left'>Alison G. Mills, CPA</div>
     <div style='width: 40px; float: left'>1989</div>
     <div style='width: 88px; float: left; text-align: right'>8</div>
     <div style='width: 88px; float: left; text-align: right'>12</div></td></tr><tr><td width='50%'><div style='width: 10px; float: left'>&nbsp;</div>
     <div style='width: 232px; float: left'>Mr. Timothy D. Harrell</div>
     <div style='width: 40px; float: left'>1989</div>
     <div style='width: 88px; float: left; text-align: right'>28</div>
     <div style='width: 88px; float: left; text-align: right'>28</div></td><td width='50%'><div style='width: 10px; float: left'>&nbsp;</div>
     <div style='width: 232px; float: left'>Debora R. Mitchell, PhD</div>
     <div style='width: 40px; float: left'>1989</div>
     <div style='width: 88px; float: left; text-align: right'>20</div>
     <div style='width: 88px; float: left; text-align: right'>21</div></td></tr><tr><td width='50%'><div style='width: 10px; float: left'>&nbsp;</div>
<div style='width: 232px; float: left'>Mr. Tim J. Scoggins</div>
     <div style='width: 40px; float: left'>1989</div>
     <div style='width: 88px; float: left; text-align: right'>1</div>
     <div style='width: 88px; float: left; text-align: right'>9</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Here's what I have tried so far using the Scrapy Shell

Attempt 1:

This works, but then I need to co-relate the entries - ie get the Year and Int1 and Int2 for each Name that is accessed below

```
>>> response.xpath('//div[@style="width: 232px; float: left"]/text()').extract()
[u'Mr. Richard D. Hanson', u'Alison G. Mills, CPA', u'Mr. Timothy D. Harrell', u'Debora R. Mitchell, PhD', u'Mr. Tim J. Scoggins']
```

Attempt 2: 
In this attempt I am hoping to make one call to then iterate over each entry and store it in a dictionary. Unfortunately, Im not sure whats happening here

```
>>> response.xpath('//table[@width="100%"]/tr/td[@width="50%"]/div[@style="width: 10px; float: left"]/text()').extract()
[u'\xa0', u'\xa0', u'\xa0', u'\xa0', u'\xa0']
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the texts of every inner `div` and then [split the extracted list into chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9671224/771848):

```
In [1]: data = response.xpath("//table/tr/td/div/text()").extract() 
In [2]: [data[x+1:x+5] for x in xrange(0, len(data), 5)]
Out[2]: 
[[u'Mr. Richard D. Hanson', u'1989', u'1', u'27'],
 [u'Alison G. Mills, CPA', u'1989', u'8', u'12'],
 [u'Mr. Timothy D. Harrell', u'1989', u'28', u'28'],
 [u'Debora R. Mitchell, PhD', u'1989', u'20', u'21'],
 [u'Mr. Tim J. Scoggins', u'1989', u'1', u'9']]
```

Comment: Nice! I can see this works for this example here, but here's the page Im trying to extract from : http://legacy.gtalumni.org/roll_call_donors?page=100 . in there though I get an output of selector xpaths - any idea how I can dive into it further?

Comment: @nthacker i think the `data` in your case should be `data = response.xpath("//div[@id='ContentMiddle']/table[2]/tr/td/div/text()").extract()` - please test.

Comment: Yup fantastic! Thanks!