# How to break up a list into multiple chunks in one line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Suppose I have the following list:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Is there a one-liner that could be used to break this up into a list of n_chunks. For example:

```
chunk(l, 3)
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

So far I have:

```
>>> [l[len(l)*i//3:] for i in range(3)]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Which works for the 'left side' of the range but not the right side.

Comment: @ggorlen no, I'm currently using that approach (yield) to split up chunks. I'm seeing if it's possible to do it in one line.

Comment: You can easily take that `yield` expression and turn it into a list-comprehension if that is what you need

Comment: There are one-liners in that thread.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671224/split-a-python-list-into-other-sublists-i-e-smaller-lists

Comment: @ggorlen got it, yes here it is updated for the question above: `[l[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(l), 3)]`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with numpy quite easily using `np.array_split` as long as `len(l)` is garanteed to be divisible by `n`:

```
import numpy as np
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

>>> np.vstack(np.array_split(l, 3)).tolist()                                                                                                                                                                           
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: Also, in the dup...

Answer (score 1):

Try using `np.split`:

```py
import numpy as np

l =np.array( [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] )
#if your array Len mod no_of_parts_to_split == 0
x=np.split(l, 3)
>>> print(x)
[array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5, 6]), array([7, 8, 9])]

#for any number of parts to split, for any length of array
n=4
y=np.split(l, range(0, len(l), len(l)//n)[1:])
>>> print(y)
[array([1, 2]), array([3, 4]), array([5, 6]), array([7, 8]), array([9])]
```

Comment: What seems to be wrong with my answer here?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the question is a clear duplicate (some people downvote answers to questions that are clear duplicates, I personally believe that is harsh). Also, the question is *explicitely* about list objects, but this answer is about numpy.ndarray objects