# Python list of words

Tags: python, list

I have got a list called `words_list` that has around 28352 elements (words). Now I want to split this list into 29 different lists each having 1000 elements i.e, the first list would contain first 1000 words and the next list would contain next 1000 words from the `words_list` and so on. I implemented this in the following manner,

```
split=[]
start=0
end=1000
for i in range(0,29):
    temp=words_list[start:end]
    split.append(temp)
    start=start+1000
    end=end+1000
```

The code is serving the purpose. I just want to know, is there any way to reduce the steps?

Comment: search "chunking" on here, probably with python keyword, too. sec ... yeah that one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks)

Comment: This one-liner might work
`chunks = [words_list[x:x+1000] for x in range(0, len(words_list), 1000)]`
as mentioned here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671224/split-a-python-list-into-other-sublists-i-e-smaller-lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```py
split = []
tmp = []
for (count, value) in enumerate(words_list, start=1):
    tmp.append(value)

    # Check if we're on a multiple of 1000
    if count % 1000 == 0:
        split.append(tmp)
        tmp = []

# Add any leftovers
if len(tmp) != 0:
    split.append(tmp)
```

Comment: Manipulating the items one by one is very inefficient, it's much faster to use slices. See the duplicate for some interesting and efficient ideas!

Comment: My main focus was to make the snippet easy to understand, to quote the Zen of Python "Simple is better than complex" and "Readability counts"