# How to split a dataframe row into multiple dataframe row if the condition is satisfied?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe

```
         Description

0        Hi there
1        He is my family.
2        He studies in the United States.
```

I want to split this data frame in the case: If the description is longer than 10 characters, the rest of the characters should be in the next line.

Expected Output:

```
             Description
0            Hi there
1            He is my f
2            amily.
3            He studies
4            in the Uni
5            ted States
6            .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom lambda [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671224/split-a-python-list-into-other-sublists-i-e-smaller-lists) in [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) and then [`Series.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html):

```
f =  lambda data: [data[x:x+10] for x in range(0, len(data), 10)]
s = df['Description'].apply(f).explode().reset_index(drop=True)
print (s)
0      Hi there
1    He is my f
2        amily.
3    He studies
4     in the Un
5    ited State
6            s.
Name: Description, dtype: object
```

Comment: Hi jezrael, it would be great if you would help me on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66741785/how-to-split-datas-from-columns-and-add-to-a-list-from-a-dataframe-also-repeat

Answer (score 0):

One way using `pandas.Series.str.findall`:

```
df["Description"].str.findall(".{1,10}").explode()
```

Output:

```
0      Hi there
1    He is my f
1        amily.
2    He studies
2     in the Un
2    ited State
2            s.
Name: Description, dtype: object
```