# How to split datas from columns and add to a list from a dataframe, also repeat the list elements for a single row? (Pandas)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a data frame as

```
  Product  Photo 1  Photo 2 Photo 3 Photo 4  Price
  Shirt    a.jpg    b.jpg   c.jpg   d.jpg     100
  Pant     e.jpg                              245
  Coat     f.jpg    g.jpg                     433
```

and the list as

```
values = [['A,'B','C'],['D','E','F','G'],['H','I','J','K]]
```

These data frames should be added and should start from index values[2] and the list should increase from the index as per the number of rows in the data frame. The columns should be split too like in the output format. The elements should be looped for every row.

Expected output

```
values = [['A,'B','C'],['D','E','F','G'],['PHOTO','a.jpg'],['PHOTO','b.jpg'],
          ['PHOTO','c.jpg'],['PHOTO','d.jpg'],['H','I','J','K],
          ['A,'B','C'],['D','E','F','G'],
          ['PHOTO','e.jpg'],['H','I','J','K], ['A,'B','C'],['D','E','F','G'], 
          ['PHOTO','f.jpg',], ['PHOTO','g.jpg'], ['H','I','J','K]
          ]
```

Then, I want to convert this list to data frames.
What I've tried:

```
L = [df.loc[:, x].set_axis(range(len(x)), axis=1) for x in values]
df = pd.concat(L).sort_index(kind='mergesort').fillna('').reset_index(drop=True)
df = df.fillna('')
```

output from this code in the previous case:

```
A  B  C  
D  E  F  G
H  I  J  K


 #the data frame repeats till the number of rows in the previous df.
```

Comment: I try understand logic, lists `values = [['A,'B','C'],['D','E','F','G'],['H','I','J','K]]` are generated from same DataFrame? What is logic for add `PHOTO` ?

Comment: lists values are from separate lists, 'PHOTO' is a string. I want to create a new data frame in the format of expected list values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nested list comprehension with add `PHOTO` and then `values` list:

```
values = [['A','B','C'],['D','E','F','G'],['H','I','J','K']]

df1 = df.fillna('').filter(like='Photo')
print (df1)
  Photo 1 Photo 2 Photo 3 Photo 4
0   a.jpg   b.jpg   c.jpg   d.jpg
1   e.jpg                        
2   f.jpg   g.jpg 


out = [y for x in df1.to_numpy() 
         for y in values[:2] + [['PHOTO', z] for z in x[x!='']] + values[2:]]
print (out)
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F', 'G'], ['PHOTO', 'a.jpg'], ['PHOTO', 'b.jpg'], ['PHOTO', 'c.jpg'], ['PHOTO', 'd.jpg'], ['H', 'I', 'J', 'K'], 
 ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F', 'G'], ['PHOTO', 'e.jpg'], ['H', 'I', 'J', 'K'],
 ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F', 'G'], ['PHOTO', 'f.jpg'], ['PHOTO', 'g.jpg'], ['H', 'I', 'J', 'K']]
```

Comment: ['PHOTO', 'a.jpg', 'b.jpg', 'c.jpg', 'd.jpg'] line should be ['PHOTO','a.jpg'],['PHOTO','b.jpg']...

Comment: @AtomStore - oops, you are right, I miss it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
rows = [
        ['PHOTO'] + r.strip().split() 
        for r in df.filter(regex = 'Photo').to_string(header = False, index = False).split('\n')
       ]
values = values[:2] + rows + values[2:]
```

**Output**

```
values
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F', 'G'], ['PHOTO', 'a.jpg', 'b.jpg', 'c.jpg', 'd.jpg'], ['PHOTO', 'e.jpg'], ['PHOTO', 'f.jpg', 'g.jpg'], ['H', 'I', 'J', 'K']]
```

---

If the empty cells are `None`, then you have to do this first:

```
df = df.fillna('')
```

---

Update after the edit:

```
jpgs =  df.filter(regex = 'Photo').stack()
rows = [["PHOTO", jpg] for jpg in jpgs[jpgs != ''].unique()]
values = values[:2] + rows + values[2:]
```

**Output**

```
values
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F', 'G'], ['PHOTO', 'a.jpg'], ['PHOTO', 'b.jpg'], ['PHOTO', 'c.jpg'], ['PHOTO', 'd.jpg'], ['PHOTO', 'e.jpg'], ['PHOTO', 'f.jpg'], ['PHOTO', 'g.jpg'], ['H', 'I', 'J', 'K']]
```

Comment: I want to add using header names because there may be cases where there are other columns in the dataframe too

Comment: I have updated the data frame. Please edit your solution

Comment: please if you could solve the updated one.

Comment: @AtomStore you should not edit questions that way, create another one instead