# Iterating over conditions from columns and Dataframe to list conversion(pandas)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe like this:

```
Item   Quantity  Price     Photo1     Photo2    Photo3    Photo4

A        2         30      A1.jpg      A2.jpg 
B        4         10      B1.jpg      B2.jpg    B3.jpg    B4.jpg
C        5         15      C1.jpg
```

These are my previous questions related to bringing the data frame in this format.

[How to split datas from columns and add to a list from a dataframe, also repeat the list elements for a single row? (Pandas)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66741785/how-to-split-datas-from-columns-and-add-to-a-list-from-a-dataframe-also-repeat)

I first created a list:

```
df1 = df.reindex(['Item','Quantity','Price','Photo1','Photo2','Photo3','Photo4','I','Q','P','PH',] axis=1)
df1['I'] = df1['I'].fillna['I']
df1['Q'] = df1['Q'].fillna['Q']
df1['P'] = df1['P'].fillna['P']
df1['PH'] = df1['PH'].fillna['PH']
vals = [['I','Item'],['Q','Quantity'],['P','Price']]
```

I tried from the first question:

```
photo_df = df1.fillna('').filter(like='Photo')


vals = [y for x in photo_df.to_numpy() 
         for y in vals[:3] + [['PH',z] for z in x[x!='']] ]
```

the list returns

```
vals = [['I','Item'],['Q','Quantity'],['P','Price'],['PH','A1.jpg'],['PH','A2.jpg'],
        ['I','Item'],['Q','Quantity'],['P','Price'],['PH','B1.jpg'],['PH','B2.jpg'],['PH','B3.jpg'],['PH','B4.jpg'],
        ['I','Item'],['Q','Quantity'],['P','Price'],['PH','C1.jpg']]
```

I want the list as:

```
vals = [['I','Item'],['Q','Quantity'],['P','Price'],['PH','Photo1'],['PH','Photo2'],
        ['I','Item'],['Q','Quantity'],['P','Price'],['PH','Photo1'],['PH','Photo2'],['PH','Photo3'],['PH','Photo4'],
        ['I','Item'],['Q','Quantity'],['P','Price'],['PH','Photo1']]
```

I want to keep the header names in the list instead of the data but should iterate over data in the format from the question:
[How to split datas from columns and add to a list from a dataframe, also repeat the list elements for a single row? (Pandas)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66741785/how-to-split-datas-from-columns-and-add-to-a-list-from-a-dataframe-also-repeat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is filter columns names instead values in list comprehension - changed `x[x!='']` to `photo_df.columns[x!='']`:

```
vals = [y for x in photo_df.to_numpy() 
          for y in vals[:3] + [['PH',z] 
          for z in photo_df.columns[x!='']]]
print (vals)
[['I', 'Item'], ['Q', 'Quantity'], ['P', 'Price'], ['PH', 'Photo1'], ['PH', 'Photo2'], 
 ['I', 'Item'], ['Q', 'Quantity'], ['P', 'Price'], ['PH', 'Photo1'], ['PH', 'Photo2'], ['PH', 'Photo3'], ['PH', 'Photo4'], 
 ['I', 'Item'], ['Q', 'Quantity'], ['P', 'Price'], ['PH', 'Photo1']]
```

Comment: please some modifications on this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67381719/how-to-fill-the-values-in-the-list-and-convert-it-into-the-dataframe

Answer (score 3):

You can just make a small change where you create the `photo_df` like this:

```
photo_df = df1.filter(like='Photo')
photo_df = photo_df.transform(lambda x: np.where(x.isnull(), x, x.name)) 
photo_df = photo_df.fillna('')
```

*The second line just replaces the non-null value with its column name.*

**Output:**

```
[['I', 'Item'], ['Q', 'Quantity'], ['P', 'Price'], ['PH', 'Photo1'], ['PH', 'Photo2'], 
['I', 'Item'], ['Q', 'Quantity'], ['P', 'Price'], ['PH', 'Photo1'], ['PH', 'Photo2'], 
['PH', 'Photo3'], ['PH', 'Photo4'], ['I', 'Item'], ['Q', 'Quantity'], ['P', 'Price'], ['PH', 'Photo1']]
```

Comment: please some modificiations on this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67381719/how-to-fill-the-values-in-the-list-and-convert-it-into-the-dataframe