# How to fill the values in the list and convert it into the dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, numpy

I want to make some modifications to my previous Question:

[Iterating over conditions from columns and Dataframe to list conversion(pandas)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67380875/iterating-over-conditions-from-columns-and-dataframe-to-list-conversionpandas)

The dataframe is:

```
 Item   Quantity  Price     Photo1     Photo2    Photo3    Photo4

A        2         30      A1.jpg      A2.jpg 
B        4         10      B1.jpg      B2.jpg    B3.jpg    B4.jpg
C        5         15      C1.jpg
```

I  tried:

```
df1 = df.reindex(['Item','Quantity','Price','Photo1','Photo2','Photo3','Photo4','I','Q','P','PH',] axis=1)
df1['I'] = df1['I'].fillna['I']
df1['Q'] = df1['Q'].fillna['Q']
df1['P'] = df1['P'].fillna['P']
df1['PH'] = df1['PH'].fillna['PH']
vals = [['I','Item'],['Q','Quantity'],['P','Price']]

photo_df = df1.filter(like='Photo')
photo_df = photo_df.transform(lambda x: np.where(x.isnull(), x, x.name)) 
photo_df = photo_df.fillna('')

vals = [y for x in photo_df.to_numpy() 
         for y in vals[:3] + [['PH',z] for z in x[x!='']] ]
```

vals returns:

```
[['I', 'Item'], ['Q', 'Quantity'], ['P', 'Price'], ['PH', 'Photo1'], ['PH', 'Photo2'], 
['I', 'Item'], ['Q', 'Quantity'], ['P', 'Price'], ['PH', 'Photo1'], ['PH', 'Photo2'], 
['PH', 'Photo3'], ['PH', 'Photo4'], ['I', 'Item'], ['Q', 'Quantity'], ['P', 'Price'], ['PH', 'Photo1']]
```

Now I want to fill in the values from the previous data frame:

I tried:

```
L = [df1.loc[:, x].set_axis(range(len(x)), axis=1) for x in vals]
```

This returned in the format:

```
[I,A,I,B,I,C,Q,2,Q,4,Q,5....................]
```

I want the L as:

```
[I,A,Q,2,P,30,PH,A1.jpg,PH,A2.jpg,I,B..............]
```

Expected dataframe:

```
I       A
Q       2
P       4
PH      A1.jpg
PH      A2.jpg
I       B
Q       4
P       10 
PH      B1.jpg
PH      B2.jpg
PH      B3.jpg
PH      B4.jpg
I       C
Q       5
P       15
PH      C1.jpg
```

Comment: Sorry, I have meeting, so offline noe. Then I try solve your poblem after finish meeting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for reshape with [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) columns names with replace not matched values to `PH`:

```
d = {'Item':'I' , 'Quantity':'Q' ,'Price': 'P'}
df = df.stack().reset_index(level=1).reset_index(drop=True)
df.columns = ['a','b']
df['a'] = df['a'].map(d).fillna('PH')
print (df)
     a       b
0    I       A
1    Q       2
2    P      30
3   PH  A1.jpg
4   PH  A2.jpg
5    I       B
6    Q       4
7    P      10
8   PH  B1.jpg
9   PH  B2.jpg
10  PH  B3.jpg
11  PH  B4.jpg
12   I       C
13   Q       5
14   P      15
15  PH  C1.jpg
```

EDIT: To values `vals` are added values of indices and then used for selecting:

```
vals = [(i, y) for i, x in enumerate(photo_df.to_numpy())
          for y in vals[:3] + [['PH',z] 
          for z in photo_df.columns[x!='']]]
print (vals)
[(0, ['I', 'Item']), (0, ['Q', 'Quantity']), (0, ['P', 'Price']), 
 (0, ['PH', 'Photo1']), (0, ['PH', 'Photo2']), (1, ['I', 'Item']),
 (1, ['Q', 'Quantity']), (1, ['P', 'Price']), (1, ['PH', 'Photo1']), 
 (1, ['PH', 'Photo2']), (1, ['PH', 'Photo3']), (1, ['PH', 'Photo4']),
 (2, ['I', 'Item']), (2, ['Q', 'Quantity']), (2, ['P', 'Price']), 
 (2, ['PH', 'Photo1'])]

L = [df1.loc[df1.index[[i]], x].set_axis(range(len(x)), axis=1) for i, x in vals]

df  = pd.concat(L)
print (df)
    0       1
0   I       A
0   Q       2
0   P      30
0  PH  A1.jpg
0  PH  A2.jpg
1   I       B
1   Q       4
1   P      10
1  PH  B1.jpg
1  PH  B2.jpg
1  PH  B3.jpg
1  PH  B4.jpg
2   I       C
2   Q       5
2   P      15
2  PH  C1.jpg
```

Comment: This results in the same format as question

Comment: @AtomStore - Hmm, for me worrking well, added to answer.

Comment: @AtomStore - Maybe necessay add `df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: should be only 16 rows x 2 columns

Comment: @AtomStore - So then is not filtered columns by columns names? like `['I', 'Item']` return all columns `I, 'Item'` ?

Comment: I have edited and written the expected dataframe

Comment: Almost same as mine ;) but a little better with `map`

Comment: Your solution is right, but I need to convert the values obtained from the vals

Comment: @AtomStore - hmmm, there is some special reason?

Comment: the reason is that there are lots of fields and I cannot map some of the fields like {'Item':'I' , 'Quantity':'Q' ,'Price': 'P'}. Some are new characters too.

Comment: @AtomStore - Understand, answer was edited.

Comment: @jezrael, if I want the same condition in the same dataframe  with other columns then,

Comment: @jezrael https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67515378/how-to-fill-the-values-in-the-list-and-convert-it-into-the-dataframepart-ii more information on this one

Comment: you just filled NA with 'PH' on the first solution, this doesn't works if I wanted the output in more than 2 columns,

Comment: @jezrael Please check the detailed condition at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67698906/how-to-optimize-time-while-converting-list-to-dataframepart-ii

Comment: @AtomStore - I see, so there is necessary different values per row? Like in first row `4` values in list, then `3`, then `2` and all another `3` for `Photo` ? Is not possible all rows with same values like in all solutions before? It is problem?

Answer (score 1):

A little long but here you go:

```
index = []
values = []
cnt = 0
for x in vals:
    if x[0] == 'I':
        cnt += 1
    index.append(x[0])
    values.append(df1.iloc[cnt-1][x[1]])
pd.DataFrame({'index': index, 'values':values})
```

But I do not understand why you want to do it in a roundabout manner when you can do it just a few lines with your original dataframe `df`:

```
df2 = df.stack().reset_index()
df2.drop(columns=['level_0'],inplace=True)
df2['level_1'] = df2['level_1'].replace({'Item':'I', 'Quantity':'Q', 'Price':'P', 'Photo1':'PH', 'Photo2':'PH', 'Photo3':'PH', 'Photo4':'PH'})
df2
```

Comment: Your solution is right, but I need to convert the values obtained from the vals

Comment: @AtomStore In that case you can use the first block of code.