# How to fill the values in the list and convert it into the dataframe?(Part II)

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, numpy

I have a modified data frame from the previous question: [How to fill the values in the list and convert it into the dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67381719/how-to-fill-the-values-in-the-list-and-convert-it-into-the-dataframe)

```
Item       Photo1     Photo2    Photo3    Photo4   Description1  Description2  Description 3

A           A1.jpg      A2.jpg                        Nice           Beautiful
B           B1.jpg      B2.jpg    B3.jpg    B4.jpg    Ugly           Damaged
C           C1.jpg                                    Cute           Handsome     Nice
```

I want to use the code from the previous question on the two fields:

```
photo_df= df1.fillna('').filter(like='Photo')
vals = [(i, y) for i, x in enumerate(photo_df.to_numpy())
          for y in vals[:3] + [['PH',z] 
          for z in photo_df.columns[x!='']]]
```

What i tried is:

```
photo_df= df1.fillna('').filter(like='Photo')
product_df = df1.fillna('').filter(like='Description')

vals = [(i, y) for i, x in enumerate(photo_df.to_numpy())
          for y in vals[:3] + [['PH',z] 
          for z in photo_df.columns[x!='']]]
vals = [(i, y) for i, x in enumerate(product_df.to_numpy())
          for y in vals[:4] + [['Description',z] 
          for z in product_df.columns[x!='']]]
L = [df1.loc[df1.index[[i]], x].set_axis(range(len(x)), axis=1) for i, x in vals]

df  = pd.concat(L)
```

but this gives the list out of the list,

Again I tried,
I divided the dataframes into two parts:

```
photo_df= df1.fillna('').filter(like='Photo')
photo_df = photo_df.fillna('')
product_df = df1.fillna('').filter(like='Description')
product_df = product_df.fillna('')

vals = [(i, y) for i, x in enumerate(photo_df.to_numpy())
          for y in vals[:3] + [['PH',z] 
          for z in photo_df.columns[x!='']]]
vals2 = [(i, y) for i, x in enumerate(product_df.to_numpy())
          for y in vals[:0] + [['Description',z] 
          for z in product_df.columns[x!='']]]
L = [df1.loc[df1.index[[i]], x].set_axis(range(len(x)), axis=1) for i, x in vals]
M = [df2.loc[df2.index[[i]], x].set_axis(range(len(x)), axis=1) for i, x in vals2]

df  = pd.concat(L)
 
df3 = pd.concat(M)

df = pd.concat([df,df3])
```

Output:

```
 I             A
PH           A1.jpg
PH           A2.jpg
 I             B
PH           B1.jpg
PH           B2.jpg
PH           B3.jpg
PH           B4.jpg
 I             C
PH           C1.jpg
Description Nice
Description Beauiful
Description Ugly
Description Damaged
Description Cute
Description Handsome
Description Nice
```

How to properly concatenate in the below format?

Expected Dataframe is similar like to the previous question, with description added.

Expected Output:

```
I             A
PH           A1.jpg
PH           A2.jpg
Description Nice
Description Beauiful
I             B
PH           B1.jpg
PH           B2.jpg
PH           B3.jpg
PH           B4.jpg
Description Ugly
Description Damaged
I             C
PH           C1.jpg
Description Cute
Description Handsome
Description Nice
```

Comment: no, 3 is postion for PH, while 4 is for DP

Comment: Ok, is possible add expected ouput?

Comment: yes, added same case like before with new field

Comment: I cannot run code without error, there is `vals = [['I','Item'],['Q','Quantity'],['P','Price']]` ?

Comment: also added some of your code from previous section

Comment: I try test your solution, but failed,. I use `i_df = df.reindex(['Item','Quantity','Price','Photo1','Photo2','Photo3','Photo4','Description1','Description2','Description3','I','Q','P','PH','Description'], axis=1)
i_df['I'] = i_df['I'].fillna('I')
i_df['Q'] = i_df['Q'].fillna('Q')
i_df['P'] = i_df['P'].fillna('P')
i_df['PH'] = i_df['PH'].fillna('PH')
i_df['Description'] = i_df['Description'].fillna('Description')
vals = [['I','Item'],['Q','Quantity'],['P','Price']]`, Is it correct for data in question?

Comment: yes the data set is correct, the output is of like previous question

Comment: @jezrael I have edited and tried please tell how to concatenate properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
#created default index
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df1 = df.reindex(df.columns.tolist() + ['I','PH','Descr'], axis=1)

df1['I'] = df1['I'].fillna('I')
#added column not called Description
df1['Descr'] = df1['Descr'].fillna('Description')
df1['PH'] = df1['PH'].fillna('PH')

#added values like input data
vals = [['I','Item']]
print (df1)
  Item  Photo1  Photo2  Photo3  Photo4 Description1 Description2 Description3  \
0    A  A1.jpg  A2.jpg     NaN     NaN         Nice    Beautiful          NaN   
1    B  B1.jpg  B2.jpg  B3.jpg  B4.jpg         Ugly      Damaged          NaN   
2    C  C1.jpg     NaN     NaN     NaN         Cute     Handsome         Nice   

   I  PH        Descr  
0  I  PH  Description  
1  I  PH  Description  
2  I  PH  Description
```

---

```
photo_df= df1.fillna('').filter(like='Photo')
photo_df = photo_df.fillna('')
product_df = df1.fillna('').filter(like='Description')
product_df = product_df.fillna('')

#assigned to vals1 for avoid overwrite `vals`
vals1 = [(i, y) for i, x in enumerate(photo_df.to_numpy())
          for y in vals[:3] + [['PH',z] 
          for z in photo_df.columns[x!='']]]
#removed vals[:4] for avoid duplicated rows 
vals2 = [(i, y) for i, x in enumerate(product_df.to_numpy())
          for y in  [['Descr',z] 
          for z in product_df.columns[x!='']]]

L = [df1.loc[df1.index[[i]], x].set_axis(range(len(x)), axis=1) for i, x in vals1]
#selected df1
M = [df1.loc[df1.index[[i]], x].set_axis(range(len(x)), axis=1) for i, x in vals2]

df  = pd.concat(L)
df3 = pd.concat(M)
```

---

```
#sorting index by mergesort (only stable algo)
df = pd.concat([df,df3]).sort_index(kind='mergesort')
print (df)
             0          1
0            I          A
0           PH     A1.jpg
0           PH     A2.jpg
0  Description       Nice
0  Description  Beautiful
1            I          B
1           PH     B1.jpg
1           PH     B2.jpg
1           PH     B3.jpg
1           PH     B4.jpg
1  Description       Ugly
1  Description    Damaged
2            I          C
2           PH     C1.jpg
2  Description       Cute
2  Description   Handsome
2  Description       Nice
```

Comment: your answer is correct works for small data. But, if I had a large dataset, then this would take a lot of time. I tried with 10000 data, this took about 15 mins. Any ideas to minimize time execution?

Comment: `L = [df1.loc[df1.index[[i]], x].set_axis(range(len(x)), axis=1) for i, x in vals1]` , this particular line takes a lot of time for large data

Comment: @AtomStore - I think here is possible optimalize solution by `stack` - first solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67381916/2901002), because in this solution are loops which optimalize is really difficult

Answer (score 0):

You already have the merged/concatenated dataframe. Is it just a matter of getting the sorting right?

Try this:

```
df['sort'] = [len(x) for x in df[0]]
df['Item'] = df.index

df.sort_values(by=['Item', 'sort'], inplace=True)
df.drop(labels=['Item', 'sort'], axis=1, inplace=True)
print(df.to_string(header=False, index=False))
```

It produces this output:

```
          I         A
         PH    A1.jpg
         PH    A2.jpg
Description      Nice
Description Beautiful
          I         B
         PH    B1.jpg
         PH    B2.jpg
         PH    B3.jpg
         PH    B4.jpg
Description      Ugly
Description   Damaged
          I         C
         PH    C1.jpg
Description      Cute
Description  Handsome
Description      Nice
```