# How to optimize time while converting list to dataframe?(Part II)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, time

I didn't get any proper answers to my previous question:

[How to optimize time while converting list to dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67682496/how-to-optimize-time-while-converting-list-to-dataframe)

Let me explain the example more:

Let's consider the data frame more precisely as

```
First Name   Last Name    Country  Address      Age  Age-Group  Photo1 Photo2 Phototype
Mark         Shelby        US      Petersburg    42   Adult     1.jpg  2.jpg    PP
Andy         Carnot        GE      Freiburg      16    Teen     1.jpg           PP
```

I want the output dataframe when converted to csv as

```
N,Mark,Shelby,US
AG,43,Adult
AD,Petersburg
PH,1.jpg,PP
PH,2.jpg,PP
N,Andy,Carnot,GE
AG,16,Teen
AD,Freiburg
PH,1.jpg,PP
```

The character PH,AG, AD,N should not be mapped. It can be any character.

This works fine while looping over this list and mapping and converting to a data frame. But, this took a lot of time for large datasets. The exact code for this process is in the previous question

```
[['N','First Name','Last Name', 'Country'],
 ['AG','Age','Age-Group'],
 ['AD','Address'],
 ['PH','Photo1','Phototype'],
 ['PH','Photo2','Phototype'], 
 ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
print (df)
  First Name Last Name Country     Address  Age Age-Group Photo1 Photo2  \
0       Mark    Shelby      US  Petersburg   42     Adult  1.jpg  2.jpg   
1       Andy    Carnot      GE    Freiburg   16      Teen  1.jpg    NaN   

  Phototype  
0        PP  
1        PP
```

First is defined dictionary for keys by first value in final list with all columns strating with strings:

```
d = {'N':['First Name','Last Name', 'Country'],
     'AG':['Age','Age-Group'],
     'AD':['Address'],
     'PH':['Photo','Phototype']}
```

Then filter DataFrames by lists from dictionary:

```
out = {k: df.loc[:, df.columns.str.startswith(tuple(v))] for k, v in d.items()}
```

For `PH` is necessary melting for change format:

```
out['PH'] = (out['PH'].melt('Phototype', 
                           value_name='Photo',
                           ignore_index=False)
                      .drop('variable',1)[['Photo','Phototype']]
                      .dropna(subset=['Photo']))
```

Last create same columns and join by `concat` with sorting for correct ordering:

```
out = {k: v.set_axis(range(len(v.columns)), axis=1) for k, v in out.items()}

df = pd.concat(out).sort_index(level=1,sort_remaining=False).reset_index(level=0).fillna('')
print (df)
  level_0           0       1   2
0       N        Mark  Shelby  US
0      AG          42   Adult    
0      AD  Petersburg            
0      PH       1.jpg      PP    
0      PH       2.jpg      PP    
1       N        Andy  Carnot  GE
1      AG          16    Teen    
1      AD    Freiburg            
1      PH       1.jpg      PP
```

Last create lists with different lengths by remove empty strings:

```
fin = [x[x!= ''].tolist() for x in df.to_numpy() ]
print (fin)
[['N', 'Mark', 'Shelby', 'US'],
 ['AG', 42, 'Adult'],
 ['AD', 'Petersburg'], 
 ['PH', '1.jpg', 'PP'], 
 ['PH', '2.jpg', 'PP'], 
 ['N', 'Andy', 'Carnot', 'GE'], 
 ['AG', 16, 'Teen'], 
 ['AD', 'Freiburg'], 
 ['PH', '1.jpg', 'PP']]
```

EDIT: For match `Photo` with digits is use regex, so instead `startswith` is used `contains` with joined values of lists by `|` for regex `OR`:

```
d = {'N':['First Name','Last Name', 'Country'],
     'AG':['Age','Age-Group'],
     'AD':['Address'],
     'PH':['Photo\d+','Phototype']}

out = {k: df.loc[:, df.columns.str.contains('|'.join(v))] for k, v in d.items()}
print (out)
{'N':   First Name Last Name Country
0       Mark    Shelby      US
1       Andy    Carnot      GE, 'AG':    Age Age-Group
0   42     Adult
1   16      Teen, 'AD':       Address
0  Petersburg
1    Freiburg, 'PH':   Photo1 Photo2 Phototype
0  1.jpg  2.jpg        PP
1  1.jpg    NaN        PP}
```

EDIT: Trick is add `^` to start of strings and `$` to end of string for exact match values, then is necessary for correct working `Photo`+ 'digit':

```
print (df)
  First Name Last Name Country     Address  Age Age-Group Photo1 Photo2  \
0       Mark    Shelby      US  Petersburg   42     Adult  1.jpg  2.jpg   
1       Andy    Carnot      GE    Freiburg   16      Teen  1.jpg    NaN   

  Phototype Age Detail Address Detail  
0        PP      Young            Far  
1        PP  Too Young           Near  


d = {'N':['First Name','Last Name', 'Country'],
     'AG':['Age','Age-Group'],
     'AD':['Address'],
     'PH':['Photo\d+','Phototype']}

d = {k: [rf'^{x}$' for x in v] for k, v in d.items()}
print (d)
{'N': ['^First Name$', '^Last Name$', '^Country$'], 
 'AG': ['^Age$', '^Age-Group$'], 
 'AD': ['^Address$'], 
 'PH': ['^Photo\\d+$', '^Phototype$']}

out = {k: df.loc[:, df.columns.str.contains('|'.join(v))] for k, v in d.items()}

print (out['AG'])
   Age Age-Group
0   42     Adult
1   16      Teen

print (out['AD'])
      Address
0  Petersburg
1    Freiburg
```

Comment: In the line,  `out = {k: df.loc[:, df.columns.str.startswith(tuple(v))] for k, v in d.items()} ` , the str.startswithtuple(v) filters???

Comment: @AtomStore - Idea is match `Photo1`, `Photo2`... if defined only `Photo` - so filter columns names by starts substrings

Comment: And for general solution also working match all another columns names.

Comment: your idea is nice, but if there is another column name 'Age Description', the line  `out = {k: df.loc[:, df.columns.str.startswith(tuple(v))] for k, v in d.items()} ` shows the mistake output as  `['AG',Age,Age-Group,Age Description] ` . I just want the columns which are mentioned in the dictionary d

Comment: @AtomStore - So in previous answers working well `photo_df= df1.filter(like='Photo')
product_df = df1.filter(like='Description')` ? So need change `df.columns.str.startswith(tuple(v))` to `df.columns.str.contains('|'.join(v))` ?

Comment: still not working, same it refers to other columns too, only I want the columns mapped in dictionary.

Comment: @AtomStore - Is possible change input columns names with problematic columns names?

Comment: @AtomStore - One idea - added to answer.

Comment: the problem is it shows extra columns rather than this  ` d = {'N':['First Name','Last Name', 'Country'],
     'AG':['Age','Age-Group'],
     'AD':['Address'],
     'PH':['Photo\d+','Phototype']} ` if similar type of columns are there, I want only the columns with that mentioned in the d, I think  `df.columns.str.contains('|'.join(v)) ` lines need a change

Comment: @AtomStore - What are original columns ? `print (df.columns)` ?

Comment: Please add the column `Age Detail ` and  `Address Detail ` with any values and check.

Comment: @AtomStore - `Age Detail and Address Detail` are added to `d` ? How ?

Comment: Please try adding `df['Age Detail']=['Young','Too Young'] ` and `df['Address Detail']=['Far','Near'] `and try the solution I will get `Ag,42,Adult, Young` instead of  `Ag,42,Adult`

Comment: @AtomStore - `d` is not changed? `d = {'N':['First Name','Last Name', 'Country'], 'AG':['Age','Age-Group'], 'AD':['Address'], 'PH':['Photo\d+','Phototype']}` ? Or there is added `Age Detail` ?

Comment: @AtomStore - OK, testing.

Comment: @AtomStore - Added solution to answer.