# What changes to my code should I make so that my code would work?

Tags: python, list, reference

So I'm trying to implement a function `ptt(L:List[int],k:int)` that returns a nested list containing partitions of L where each element of the list is itself a list containing exactly k elements (except the last partition which may have fewer than k elements). For example, when `L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` and `k = 2`, `partition(L, k)` returns `[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7]]`. Here are a few more examples.

```
assert ptt([1,2,3],2) == [[1,2],[3]]
assert ptt([1,2,3],3) == [[1,2,3]]
assert ptt([1,2,3,4],1) == [[1],[2],[3],[4]]
assert ptt([1,2,3,4],2) == [[1,2],[3,4]]
```

Here is my attempt at the code...

```
def ptt(L, k):
    if (L == 0 or k == 0 or k > L):
        return 0
    if (k == 1 or k == L):
        return 1
    return (k * ptt(L - 1, k) +
                ptt(L - 1, k - 1))
```

However, this doesn't work at all... what changes to my code should I make to make sure it works??

Comment: You should start by showing us what `countP` is.

Comment: If `L` is a list as you described in the question, then things like `L == 0`, `k > L` or `L - 1` do not make sense.

Comment: @MarkRansom my bad, changed the function name but not the name inside it, already edited it btw

Comment: What happens when you run your code? Do you get any errors? If so, I suggest googling the error message to get some tips on how to fix it. If not, what is the result? If you don't get the result you want, then you need to debug your code. [This article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) has some great tips to get you started.

Comment: So it's a recursive function?  If so the name is still wrong.

Comment: yep its a recursive one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is very different from your approach, but it produces the result you're looking for:

```
def partition(nums, k):
    result = []
    for i in range(0, len(nums), k):
        result.append(nums[i:i+k])
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry this going to sound harsh, but since you are learning to program, you should learn to use your best resource on the internet...google searches.  Most initial forays into programming tasks have already been solved (many times) and the solutions are readily available.

A simple query "partition a list to sublists python" yields several sources.
Try:
[Split a python list into other "sublists" i.e smaller lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671224/split-a-python-list-into-other-sublists-i-e-smaller-lists)

The solution there is

`chunks = [data[x:x+k] for x in range(0, len(data), k)]`